# How can I add `do-try-catch` control in to this function below?

Tags: swift, error-handling, swift4

How can I add `do-try-catch` control in to this function below?

```
self.convertDateFromString("23282019111259318")

func convertDateFromString(stringDateTimeParameter : String)
{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMddyyyyHHmmssSSS"

    guard let myDate = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDateTimeParameter) else {
    fatalError("ERROR: Date conversion failed due to mismatched format.")}

    print("myDate: \(myDate)")
}
```

As you see above sample. I am sending 23 value as a month to get an error. And then the application is stoped by the device. I need to handle this situation. App should not stop and i should see print(error) in catch scope.

How can I add `do-try-catch` control in to this function? I wrote it but I didn't see the print line in the catch scope. That's why I am asking.

Comment: Date formatters don’t throw errors (which is the only time you use `do`-`try`-`catch`). You can change `convertDateFromString` to `throw` an error (so whomever called it can `catch` them. But given that date formatters don’t `throw` errors, there’s no point in try to `catch` them here in this method.

Comment: Dear @Rob I have updated function. Let's assume that we call function with this value: convertDateFromString(23282019111259318) It will be crushed. Cuz month cant be 23. I would like to handle this. So what do i need? I think do-try-catch? So i tried to write it but i couldn't. I would like to see print(error) line in catch scope if value is not fine like this convertDateFromString(23282019111259318)

Comment: For what purpose!?  Objective-C's and Swift's try-catch doesn't work like that of Visual Basic and C#.  So you can't just use try-catch in any situation.

Comment: @ElTomato okay. But how can i handle this function if value is not fine like in this sample (month is 23)

Comment: Return an option value.

Comment: I am getting datetime from web api like this. So i need to convert it to the date. I wrote function like this. But i need to add handle control. This is the purpose. @ElTomato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `do-catch` to handle errors you will need to create an error type for your function to throw:

```
struct DateConvertError : Error
{
    let description: String
}
```

The formatter doesn't tell you why it failed to parse though so this doesn't make a lot of sense but then your function can be marked as `throws`:

```
func convertDateFromString(stringDateTimeParameter : String) throws -> Date
{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMddyyyyHHmmssSSS"

    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDateTimeParameter) else {
        throw DateConvertError(description: "Could not parse")
    }

    return date
}
```

And then when you call it you `do` a `try`:

```
let date: Date
do {
    date = try convertDateFromString(stringDateTimeParameter: "23282019111259318")
} catch {
    // Handle failure
}
```

Comment: Error objects are usually enumerations. See [Representing and Throwing Errors](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html#ID509).

Answer (score 3):

You can’t make date formatters throw errors, but you can throw an error from this method if you want, e.g.

```
enum DateConversionError: Error {
    case unableToParseString
}

func dateFromString(stringDateTimeParameter: String) throws -> Date {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMddyyyyHHmmssSSS"
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)     // or omit to use your current time zone

    guard let date = formatter.date(from: stringDateTimeParameter) else {
        throw DateConversionError.unableToParseString
    }

    return date
}
```

And then you could do things like:

```
do {
    let date = try dateFromString(stringDateTimeParameter: "23282019111259318")
    print(date)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

That having been said, it feels like we’re contorting ourselves to throw errors. It’s simpler to use optionals:

```
func dateFromString(stringDateTimeParameter: String) -> Date? {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMddyyyyHHmmssSSS"
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)     // or omit to use your current time zone

    return formatter.date(from: stringDateTimeParameter)
}

guard let date = dateFromString(stringDateTimeParameter: "23282019111259318") else {
    print("unable to parse date")
    return
}

// use `date` here
```

---

If you’re parsing web API responses, it that response is in JSON, I’d be inclined to use `JSONDecoder` and specify the formatter in the [`dateDecodingStrategy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895216-datedecodingstrategy):

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMddyyyyHHmmssSSS"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)

// use `decoder` to parse your JSON and it will handle conversions/errors for you
```

This begs the question why you’re using the `MMddyyyyHHmmssSSS` format, vs standard formats like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`, but that’s a separate question.

---

As a final aside, creating date formatters is an expensive process. You really don’t want that buried inside your `dateFromString` method, which you’re likely to be calling many times. Instantiate a formatter once, and then have your `dateFromString` method use that already-created formatter.

Comment: Rob, how come you aren't returning nil after print("unable to parse date")?

Comment: @ElTomato - Because that `return` isn’t inside `dateFromString`, but rather it’s in whatever method called `dateFromString`. We have no idea what that method looks like...

Comment: Oh, I see.  Sorry about that.

Comment: It would be easier for further debugging to include info about string that failed and format that was expected.